# Spring - Hibernate - Configure multiple databases dynamically

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, sharding, sessionfactory

I have multiple MySQL DBs which are sharded based on customer id. There is a micro service which provides details about the shard information (which customer id belong to which db etc).

So far, my code worked with single datasource and I have a function which provides the sessionFactory as part of hibernate configuration file:

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
  // set data source here
}
```

Data source is returned by:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
}
```

I am autowiring the sessionFactory in the DAO:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Now, with multiple datasource, I need to:

- read configured databases from microservice
- use the list of db to create datasource dynamically
- sessionFactory should be crated dynamically based on the customer id.

I am not sure how to autowire sessionFactory such that it initializes the datasource based on customer id.

Any help here is really appreciated.

Comment: What is mean by dynamically.? Spring configures the beans at the application startup, so wont be able to inject 2nd datasource. If you specify other spring scope, creating SessionFactory dynamcally will not scale well. Those objects has to be created on startup.

Comment: you can have seprate beans configured with Qualifier and one of them can be primary, which you need on your first request

Comment: Information about databases are not static. This information is provided by another micro-service which lists all the sharded databases that are configured. Databases can be added or removed at the micro-service that is managing it.

Say, if I need to add a new customer id, all the data corresponding to that id will be added as a separate db instance and the micro service will then return an array of dbs with the newly added db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shame i didnt see this question before now. The easiest way to do this with hibernate 4+ is to setup your shards as datasources. I personally used container managed datasources but you could probably do it another way, setting up and maintaining your own connection pool the hard way. These datasources then have jndi names associated with them that allows you access to the connection pool from the hibernate connection provider. you will only be able write to only one shard per transaction if done this way,,, of course you can write to multiple datasources just only one shard. Take care to put all associated relational data on the same shard in the same schema. Its important. You can leverage the App servers transaction registry to wire up access to JTA transactions across both your cache providers and all of your datasources. Remember to use XA for all but one datasource in each transaction. Leverage hibernate multi tenancy to provide direction to which schema to use. (Also passed into the connection provider with a threadlocal and assigned to the connection for that data source). You are going to need to pay close attention to the equals and hash methods as multiple object that you logically want to be equal may be attached to different class loaders at the same time and pragmatically arent equal by default. When such an event occurs you will get some very strange hibernate error messages when these objects are included in a transaction and it goes to try to persist them. Override everything.